# Почему при компиляции пишет ошибку типа [prog.c:7:13: error: ‘z2’ undeclared (first use in this function)]

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double a, x, y;
    double z1; z2; z3; z4;
    double numerator, denominator;
    printf("x = "); scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("a = "); scanf("%lf", &a);

    z1 = M_LN(1+exp(fabs(x)+1));
    z2 = powl (M_PI, M_E);
    z3 = (M_PI+a)/M_E + x;
    z4 = 1 + sqrt(x) + pow(x, 2);
    numerator = z1+z2;
    denominator = sin(z3) * atan(z4) + 14,8;
    if (denominator == 0.)
{
    printf("ERROR: denominator = 0\n");
    return -1;
}
y = numenator / denominator;
printf("y = %lf\n",y);
return 0;
}
```

prog.c:7:13: error: ‘z2’ undeclared (first use in this function).

Answer (score 3):

Потому что сами скажите, чем принципиальным отличаются две строки из вашего кода:

```
double a, x, y;
double z1; z2; z3; z4;
```

Как отделены одна от другой переменные в первой строке, и как - во второй?

Кстати, вы будете также удивлены, что здесь

```
denominator = sin(z3) * atan(z4) + 14,8;
```

компилятор просто проигнорирует `,8` - потому что это оператор запятой (составной оператор), а вам, вероятно, нужно записывать число `14.8`.

Comment: то есть лучше писать все в одну строку?

Comment: @МеральНекраг, лучше поменять ; на , во второй строке.